# How to build Mesa 3D 8 for Windows using Microsoft toolchain?

Tags: windows, mesa

Everything (including LLVM) seems fine until I face

src\mesa\drivers\windows\gdi\wmesa.c(956) : error C2039: 'PutRow' : is not a member of 'gl_renderbuffer'
        D:\Sources\Graphics\Mesa-8.0.2\src\mesa\main/mtypes.h(2540) : see declaration of 'gl_renderbuffer'

Comment: I had the same error, and added the option `drivers=gdi` to scons arguments. According to the [README](http://www.mesa3d.org/README.WIN32), this is the only driver known to work. However, the build hangs with a "potential divide by 0". Have you solved your issue? Can you post as an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

I just hit exactly this.

This stackoverflow article MIGHT contain a clue:
[Can massive nested loops cause the linker to run endlessly when compiling in Release-Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138831/c-can-massive-nested-loops-cause-the-linker-to-run-endlessly-when-compiling)

I have confirmed it is the linker that is hung. The behavior I am seeing is exactly what the poster of the above thread saw. CPU pegged at 100% (on one core) and no movement of memory up or down.

The author suggests that disabling function inlining helped. I will try this tomorrow.